# How to make application symbols visible to a library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, visibility

I have an application that loads a library with `dlopen`, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo";
}

int main()
{
    void* libbar = dlopen("./libbar.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!libbar)
    {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    void(*bar)() = (void(*)())dlsym(libbar, "bar");
    if (!bar)
    {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    bar();
    dlclose(libbar); 
}
```

And here is `libbar`:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo();

extern "C"
void bar()
{
    foo();
    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
./libbar.so: undefined symbol: _Z3foov
```

Expected output:

```
foobar
```

How to make `foo` visible to `libbar`?

I'm actually using C++ and the real problem is with undefined symbols from constructors/member functions, but this should be very similar. I'm working on Linux with GCC 4.7.

Comment: Usually references between modules (libraries) go one way.  I suggest passing foo to bar as an argument would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compile and link main.cc with

```
 g++ -rdynamic -Wall main.cc -o prog -ldl
```

The [-rdynamic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) flag is important at link time.

And you'll better declare `extern "C"` those functions which you want to pass to `dlsym`.

See also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).